# How would I create curved badges like the Apple Watch fitness badges?

Tags: modeling, bezier-curves, svg

I'm looking for ways to be able to relatively easily produce badges like these Apple fitness badges:

[image: Badges]

You can see they're also slightly bulging/curving outwards towards the camera.

My initial attempt has been a workflow that imports SVG lines to get the curves, then adding some thickness and a bevel, converting to mesh, using the remesh modifier to fix the bad topology from the curve to mesh and add more topology to support the outwards bulge, then using the cast modifier to get the outward bend.

It works but it's very high poly (1m verts) and there's a lot of shading distortion from the remesh. Are there some better ways to approach this?

Comment: why do you need so many faces? also you could use a Lattice to deform. As for the letters: couldn't it be a normal or bump map?

Comment: It could be normal/bump but the badges need to spin so ideally it would be actual geometry, although I could probably get away with a normal map for the bevel.

And the number of faces just to support the deform - the curve to mesh creates really long faces across the entire model and remeshing just ends up creating a lot of geometry to retain the shape